# android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat example?

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I am trying to use `SearchViewCompat` with `ActionBarSherlock` in an API 8 app.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext);
    item.setShowAsAction(
        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | 
        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    // To use SearchViewCompat, I need to add it to the Menu item as well:
    View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(this);
    // ...
    SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(...);
    // ...
    item.setActionView(searchView);
```

Please note that both the top and bottom code needs to call `setActionView()`. Does that mean it is not possible to do search?

Comment: Instead of asking for code you can add the code you've got so far to your question. Perhaps people can help you fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks THelper. Also looks like my local document is out of date and I found a specific developer topic: http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the ActionBarSherlock Library ver 4.2, you can replace the API 11 SearchView Widget with a ActionBarSherlock SearchView Widget to make it backward compatible:

**search.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/description_search"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" /> 
</menu>
```

**Activity class**

```
//IMPORTANT!!!
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
```

...

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    setupSearchMenuItem(menu);
    return true;
}

private void setupSearchMenuItem(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        if (searchView != null) {
            SearchManager searchManager = 
                 (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the actual problem? `SearchViewCompat` will return `null` for pre-HC devices since the `SearchView` widget does not exist. This means you will have to provide your own custom action view that imitates the HC SearchView.

You can also backport the `SearchView` component from the Android sources and use that.

Otherwise, you can just use the existing search interfaces Android has, in which case for HC+ devices you use the action view to perform a search but on Froyo and Gingerbread devices the user clicks on the search icon and a search bar animates from the top.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in your Activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

// ...    
SearchView searchView = (com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView) 
    actionBarCustom.findViewById(R.id.search);
SearchManager sm = (SearchManager)getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

And then filter your list adapter:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText.trim());
    return false;
}
```

This way, your list adapter must implement filterable.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use MenuItemCompat,I think this is helpful for you

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    SearchableInfo info =  searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
```